# Regex to detect HTML tags with onclick or onload attributes is too greedy

Tags: php, html, regex

I have the following regex used to check HTML code:

```
 /<.+(onclick|onload)[^=>]*=[^>]+>/si
```

This regex is supposed to detect if there are tags with onclick or onload attributes somewhere in the HTML. It does so in most cases, however the ".+" part is a huge performance problem on big texts (and also source of some bugs as it's too greedy). I've tried to fix it and make it smarter but failed so far - "smarter" one misses some examples like this:

```
<img alt="<script>" src="http://someurl.com/image.jpg"; onload="alert(42)" width="1" height="1"/>
```

**Now, I know I should not parse HTML with regexes and [unmentionable horrors happen if I do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**. However, in this particular case I can not replace it with the proper code (e.g. real HTML parser). Is it still possible to fix this regex or there's no way to do it?

Comment: What about other events? `<img src="http://www.example.com/image.png" onmouseover="alert(42)"/>`

Comment: @icktoofay it's just an example, real code is more hairy and checks all kinds of stuff, but this is the problematic part.

Comment: Have you tried replacing instances of your greedy quantifiers (`*`, `+`) with lazy quantifiers instead? (`*?`, `+?`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would strongly recommend that you be researching alternatives to regex matching - the onclick/load js handler code may comprise arbitrary occurrences of `>` and `<` as relops or inside js comments. this applies to the code of other js handlers on the same element before or after the onclick/load handlers as well. the whole tag containing the match might be inside a html comment (though you might want to match these occurrences too or strip the html comments before).

however, having hinted to dire straits you appear to be aware of, the standard disclaimers against 'html regex matching' do not fully apply as you only need matches inside tags. try scanning for

`on(click|load)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*('[^']*'|"[^']*")`

and add some logic to search the text surrounding any matches for the enclosing tags. if you're brave, try this one:

`<(([^'">]+(('[^']*'|"[^"']*")[^'">]+)*)|([^'">]+('[^']*'|"[^"']*"))+)on(click|load)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*('[^']*'|"[^']*")`

it matches alternating sequences of text inside and outside of pairs of quotes between the tag opener `<` and the onclick/load-attribute. the outermost alternative caters for the special case of no whitespace between a closing quote and the onclick/load-attribute.

hope this helps

Comment: I know this regex and the whole idea has problems, it will be eventually replaced with a proper solution, but right now I need as simple as possible fix for the production code that I can't change too much.

Comment: The updated one seems to be good - tried it on some examples and so far it passes all of them fine. Thanks! Update: spoke too soon, it doesn't catch something like onload=alert(35) (without quotes) which some browsers may accept. But I think I can modify it to catch that too.